# Can a remote server connect to a local Oracle database?

Tags: networking, webserver, oracle-database

I am having trouble getting an answer - albeit it may be due to my own ignorance on the subject. However, here it goes:

Can I connect to my company's local Oracle database *from* a web server? Currently, I connect without issue within our corporate network, via programming software. However, the parameters passed are not an address. Further, connecting requires updating certain PATH vars within windows.

Can someone explain how that works? I provide a host and port, but as it is local I was thinking that all that would need to be done is a small adjustment to the server scripts to allow connection from a remote server.

Comment: Why do you say the "host and port" is not an address?

Comment: I guess because its an isolated corporate network and I am not sure it can be accessed by our web application (www), correct me if im wrong though-

Comment: Ah, that's a thing you need to ask your company's admins instead. (Do you mean a web server hosted by the company, or a web server hosted on cloud, or a web server hosted on your personal systems?)

Comment: The db (Oracle) is hosted local at the company. The web server is hosted on a cloud.